# Thermometer using DS1620 IC and arm microcontroller

Tags: c, embedded, arm, microcontroller

I am working on a project in which I have to use DS1620 IC to display temperature using ARM LPC23xx micro controller. I want to write code in C. I am a newbie in embedded systems and I have to finish this in 24 Hrs. Please help in any way possible.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I don't know the ARM architecture. I have C code for 8051 micro controller. Don't know how to get it working on ARM.

Comment: Did your complete this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look through the 8051 code. For the hardware interfaces of the 8051 that are used in the code pick some equivalent hardware on the LPC23xx and adapt the code.

Read the relevant parts of the LPC23xx and the 8051 data sheets until you understand them sufficiently.

Be careful about the size of int, 8051 is 8 bit and ARM 32 bit.